# How do I install 32 bit driver on windows 7 64 bits? (for canon faxphone L75)

Tags: installation

I have a computer with windows 7, 64 bits. 
I also have a Canon Faxphone L75 for which I only can find 32 bit drivers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Hardware&Name=Canon+FaxPhone+L75+All-in-One+Printer&ModelOrVersion=&Vendor=Canon&Locale=1033%2C2057%2C3081%2C4105%2C16393&LastSearchTerm=canon%2Bfaxphone%2Bl75%2Ball-in-one%2Bprinter&BreadcrumbPath=canon+faxphone+l75+all-in-one+printer&TempOsid=Windows+7

Answer (score 1):

You have four options:

1. Find the right driver for your device. (The driver for win7 64 bits, though you might get away with 64 bit vista or server 2008 driver.)
2. Or install the driver on another computer with an old 32 bit OS. (optionally in a VM).
3. Upgrade to a newer faxphone and complain to Canon about limited support.
4. Try to force a possibly semi stable driver to work in compatability mode. NOT RECOMMENDED.

Comment: This printer only supports the 32-bit versions of Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Vista from what I can tell. I checked every 64-bit version of Windows and there are no drivers listed on the Cannon support website for this printer. I don't believe this can be considered a limited support problem, the printer is over a decade old, based on the Windows 2000 support.  The only real options I see are #2 and #3 Its pretty guaranteed that the only driver offered isn't using the new driver model either.

Comment: Good point. A decade in 'computer land' is a long time. Complaining for something which is less old (e.g. 5 years old) is valid though it probably gets ignore with a 'just give us more money for newer hardware' reply. Assuming you get a reply at all.

Comment: I would still complain to Canon that there isn't at least 64-bit Vista support considering Vista is basically the only fully supported operating system ( by Microsoft ) listed.

Comment: @Frank - The 32-bit Vista driver **MIGHT** work on a 32-bit Windows 7 installation.